# How to make some punctuation characters indexable in MySQL FULLTEXT indexed field

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation, uca

I have a fulltext indexed field with charset utf8mb4 on MySQL 8.0

I need to be able to search for queries like "km/h" or "A-B" but with the current charset definition, slash and dash are defined as punctuation characters and are therefore not indexed by the fulltext index.

Looking at the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-modify-character-set), it seems that I have the possibilities, (given that utf8 is a strong requirement for me):

1. UCA-based collations for Unicode character sets using LDML syntax
2. Introduce a new character set and recompile MySQL

I would rather avoid recompilation, as it would introduce complexity into maintenance.

I was not able to work out the unicode documentation to create the collation rules. Could anybody help me to define a specific collation in LDML, in order to consider dash and slash as regular characters ?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you alter the data in the database, plus the data in queries to avoid punctuation.

One way is to blindly change punctuation to `_`.  Another is to change "km/h" to "km_per_h" and "A-B" to "A_dash_B".  Either way, you will get much closer to allowing punctuation in FT indexing and searching.